# Localization of Sync-fusion Grid Headings [Aurelia]

Tags: javascript, internationalization, aurelia, syncfusion

I am using the i18n plugin for the localization in our Aurelia application. But, the localization is not getting applied to the column headings dynamically on Sync-fusion grid in our Aurelia app.

The html code for the Grid is as below.

```
<ej-grid id="gvDownline"  e-locale.bind="locale" 
           e-data-source.bind="downlines"
           e-page-settings.bind="pageSettings"
           e-allow-paging=true
           e-allow-sorting=true
           e-allow-text-wrap=true
           e-text-align="center">
    <ej-column e-width="80"    e-field="level" e-header-text="${i18n.tr('Downline.Level')}" e-text-align="right">
    </ej-column>
    <ej-column e-field="sponsor" e-header-text="${i18n.tr('Downline.Sponsor')}" e-text-align="left">
    </ej-column>
    <ej-column e-field="sponsorEmail" e-header-text="${i18n.tr('Downline.SponsorEmail')}" e-text-align="center">
    <ej-column e-field="associate" e-header-text="${i18n.tr('Downline.Associate')}" e-text-align="center">
    <ej-column e-field="registeredFlag" e-width="130" e-header-text="${i18n.tr('Downline.Registered')}" e-text-align="right">
    </ej-column>
    <ej-column e-field="contractSignedDate"  e-format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" e-header-text="${i18n.tr('Downline.ContractSignedDate')}" e-text-align="right">
    </ej-column>
  </ej-grid>
```

In the code behind I have imported the following file for the localization of pagination and other grid components.

```
import 'syncfusion-ej-global/l10n/ej.localetexts.it-IT.min';
```

We are providing `i18n.tr(‘key’)` as the `e-header-text` attribute for columns to get it translated.

In my page, there are two language options. When I change the language options, I need the localization to be applied to the grid header based on the selected language. When I applied the `e-locale.bind="locale"` property in the grid, the localization is applied to the pagination and status information of the sync-fusion grid, but not applied on the grid headers.

I have to do a page reload for applying the localization of the header after each language switching. Actually, I need to set the header text from the code behind(ts file) on the language change event. Can anyone suggest a better way to implement the localization of the sync fusion grid in Aurelia.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TBindingBehavior for this. It listens to `BindingSignaler` which might make it work without any additional code, but if it still doesn't work, you'd have the option to manually send an update signal.

`e-header-text="${i18n.tr('Downline.Level')}"` would change to:

`e-header-text="${'Downline.Level' & t}"`

And to manually send an update signal (from the docs):

```
setLocale(locale) {
  return new Promise( resolve => {
    let oldLocale = this.getLocale();
    this.i18next.setLng(locale, tr => {
      this.ea.publish('i18n:locale:changed', { oldValue: oldLocale, newValue: locale });
      this.signaler.signal('aurelia-translation-signal');
      resolve(tr);
    });
  });
}
```

Where `this.signaler` is the injected `BindingSignaler`

It's also described [here](https://github.com/aurelia/i18n/blob/master/doc/article/en-US/i18n-with-aurelia.md)